# How do I solve this equation :$\bar{z}-iz²=-\sqrt{3}-3i$ without using identity way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

let $z$ be a complex number and $\bar{z}$ it's conjugate ,i would like

to solve this equation :$$\bar{z}-iz²=-\sqrt{3}-3i$$  without using identity way  ?

**Note** :by identity way the solution is clear and is:  $z= -\sqrt{3}$

Thank you for any help

Comment: What is the "identity way"?

Comment: I meant by identity way  The real part of  equality of RHS  is  the same the real part of the LHS ,the same with imaginary part

Comment: You could do the same by using the absolute value and the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint you can do it by arguments . now argument if RHS is $2\pi-\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3})=2\pi-\pi/3$ so argument of lhs needs to be  the same so $\tan^{-1}(z^2/\bar{z})=2\pi-\pi/3$ but $z^2=z \times \bar{z}$ can you continue from here?

Comment: z^2=z \times \bar{z}   ? I think |z|²=z \times \bar{z}

Comment: I mean taking mode affect none so thought its understandable

Comment: ah, sorry thanks

Comment: No problem :)....